# How do I select several ids?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

There is a list `List<string> list`

How to build a query using LINQ, which repeat the query `"Select * FROM a Where id IN(...)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) and [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.contains?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Contains__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0____0_) method:

```
var result = a.Where(c => list.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Any` as well:

```
var result = source.Where(item => list.Any(element => element == item.Id)).ToList();
```

Btw if you're using the list only to check if a given element is present or not, I'd suggest using a `HashSet<string>` as you may gain better performance:

```
HashSet<string> container = ....
```

Then use as follows:

```
var result = source.Where(item => container.Contains(item.Id));
```